# How to make a .swf object link to paypal the same way as paypal buttons do?

Tags: html, forms, paypal, flash

Paypal buttons use forms, ie:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxxxxxxx">
<input type="image" src="img.jpg" border="0" name="submit" >
</form>
```

I'd like buyers to click on a .swf file (instead of an image) which brings them to paypal's checkout, what's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this tutorial, might help:

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/quick-guide-creating-paypal-buttons-with-actionscript-30/